# Query to untie columns with the same value

Tags: sql

I am having some SQL issues with a query and I might use some help.

Here I have a query to show me the best category of each customer, based on the amount of itens they bought in my store:

```
SELECT Email, 
case 
when (C.Category1 > C.Category2 AND C.Category1 > C.Category3 AND C.Category1 > C.Category4 AND C.Category1 > C.Category5 AND C.Category1 > C.Category6 AND C.Category1 > C.Category7 AND C.Category1 > C. Category8 ) then 'Category1'
when (C.Category2>C.Category1 AND C.Category2 > C.Category3 AND C.Category2 > C.Category4 AND C.Category2 > C.Category5 AND C.Category2 > C.Category6 AND C.Category2 > C.Category7 AND C.Category2 > C.Category8) then 'Category2'
when (C.Category3 >C.Category1 AND C.Category3 > C.Category2 AND C.Category3 > C.Category4 AND C.Category3 > C.Category5 AND C.Category3 > C.Category6 AND C.Category3 > C.Category7 AND C.Category3 > C.Category8) then 'Category3' 
when (C.Category4 >C.Category1 AND C.Category4 > C.Category2 AND C.Category4 > C.Category3 AND C.Category4 > C.Category5 AND C.Category4 > C.Category6 AND C.Category4 > C.Category7 AND C.Category4 > C.Category8) then 'Category 4'
when (C.Category5 >C.Category1 AND C.Category5 > C.Category2 AND C.Category5 > C.Category3 AND C.Category5 > C.Category4 AND C.Category5 > C.Category6 AND C.Category5 > C.Category7 AND C.Category5 > C.Category8) then 'Category5'
when (C.Category6 >C.Category1 AND C.Category6 > C.Category2 AND C.Category6 > C.Category3 AND C.Category6 > C.Category4 AND C.Category6 > C.Category5 AND C.Category6 > C.Category7 AND C.Category6 > C.Category8) then 'Category6'
when (C.Category7 >C.Category1 AND C.Category7 > C.Category2 AND C.Category7 > C.Category3 AND C.Category7 > C.Category4 AND C.Category7 > C.Category5 AND C.Category7 > C.Category6 AND C.Category7 > C.Category8) then 'Category7' 
when (C.Category8 >C.Category1 AND C.Category8 > C.Category2 AND C.Category8 > C.Category3 AND C.Category8 > C.Category4 AND C.Category8 > C.Category5 AND C.Category8 > C.Category6 AND C.Category8 > C.Category7) then 'Category 8'     
else 'Tie'
end as BestCategory
FROM Category as C
```

Since I have some categories with the same amount of itens purchased, I need to untie some of them, based on accumulated revenue (other table)

```
Email   BestCategory
aaaaa@aaa.aa    Category 1
bbbbb@bbb.bb    Category 2
ccccc@ccc.cc    Tie
ddddd@ddd.dd    Category 3
eeeee@eee.ee    Category 6
```

Can you guys help me find a way to untie this query?

Comment: Sample data and desired results would help convey what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

I'll leave getting rid of the leading comma as an exercise. (I don't know which platform you're on: maybe, `substring(<expr>, 2, 100)`?) I think this is what you want though.

```
select
    Email,
    /* concatenate the list of categories that match the max value */
    case when Category1 = CategoryMax then ', Category1' end +
    case when Category2 = CategoryMax then ', Category2' end +
    case when Category3 = CategoryMax then ', Category3' end +
    case when Category4 = CategoryMax then ', Category4' end +
    case when Category5 = CategoryMax then ', Category5' end +
    case when Category6 = CategoryMax then ', Category6' end +
    case when Category7 = CategoryMax then ', Category7' end +
    case when Category8 = CategoryMax then ', Category8' end as BestCategories
from 
    Category c inner join
    (
        select /* what is the largest category value for each email? */
            Email,
            min(case 
                when Category1 >= Category2 and Category1 >= Category3 and Category1 >= Category4 and Category1 >= Category5 and Category1 >= Category6 and Category1 >= Category7 and Category1 >= Category8 then Category1
                when Category2 >= Category1 and Category2 >= Category3 and Category2 >= Category4 and Category2 >= Category5 and Category2 >= Category6 and Category2 >= Category7 and Category2 >= Category8 then Category2
                when Category3 >= Category1 and Category3 >= Category2 and Category3 >= Category4 and Category3 >= Category5 and Category3 >= Category6 and Category3 >= Category7 and Category3 >= Category8 then Category3 
                when Category4 >= Category1 and Category4 >= Category2 and Category4 >= Category3 and Category4 >= Category5 and Category4 >= Category6 and Category4 >= Category7 and Category4 >= Category8 then Category 4
                when Category5 >= Category1 and Category5 >= Category2 and Category5 >= Category3 and Category5 >= Category4 and Category5 >= Category6 and Category5 >= Category7 and Category5 >= Category8 then Category5
                when Category6 >= Category1 and Category6 >= Category2 and Category6 >= Category3 and Category6 >= Category4 and Category6 >= Category5 and Category6 >= Category7 and Category6 >= Category8 then Category6
                when Category7 >= Category1 and Category7 >= Category2 and Category7 >= Category3 and Category7 >= Category4 and Category7 >= Category5 and Category7 >= Category6 and Category7 >= Category8 then Category7 
                when Category8 >= Category1 and Category8 >= Category2 and Category8 >= Category3 and Category8 >= Category4 and Category8 >= Category5 and Category8 >= Category6 and Category8 >= Category7 then Category 8     
                else null
            end) as CategoryMax /* min is just a dummy aggregate */
        from Category
        group by Email
    ) cmax
        on cmax.Email = c.Email
```

You might extend this by joining to your other table to break ties with something like this. It's starting to feel pretty messy though.

```
left outer join Revenue r
    on  r.Email = c.Email and
        case when Category1 = CategoryMax then 1 end +
        case when Category2 = CategoryMax then 1 end +
        case when Category3 = CategoryMax then 1 end +
        case when Category4 = CategoryMax then 1 end +
        case when Category5 = CategoryMax then 1 end +
        case when Category6 = CategoryMax then 1 end +
        case when Category7 = CategoryMax then 1 end +
        case when Category8 = CategoryMax then 1 end > 1
```

Comment: Let's say that I wanted to replace the [else 'Tie'] for a lookup into another table that has the same structure of the same above. 

I don't have a Max Value for each category. I was classifiying each user with the category that had the biggest amount of purchased itens.

Comment: What is your platform? It's probably easiest to unpivot the categories and work with the data in rows.

Answer (score 0):

Or maybe you just need to add a correlated subquery as the `else` case:

```
else (
    select
        case 
            when R.Category1 > R.Category2 and R.Category1 > R.Category3 and R.Category1 > R.Category4 and R.Category1 > R.Category5 and R.Category1 > R.Category6 and R.Category1 > R.Category7 and R.Category1 > R.Category8 then 'Category1'
            when R.Category2 > R.Category1 and R.Category2 > R.Category3 and R.Category2 > R.Category4 and R.Category2 > R.Category5 and R.Category2 > R.Category6 and R.Category2 > R.Category7 and R.Category2 > R.Category8 then 'Category2'
            when R.Category3 > R.Category1 and R.Category3 > R.Category2 and R.Category3 > R.Category4 and R.Category3 > R.Category5 and R.Category3 > R.Category6 and R.Category3 > R.Category7 and R.Category3 > R.Category8 then 'Category3' 
            when R.Category4 > R.Category1 and R.Category4 > R.Category2 and R.Category4 > R.Category3 and R.Category4 > R.Category5 and R.Category4 > R.Category6 and R.Category4 > R.Category7 and R.Category4 > R.Category8 then 'Category 4'
            when R.Category5 > R.Category1 and R.Category5 > R.Category2 and R.Category5 > R.Category3 and R.Category5 > R.Category4 and R.Category5 > R.Category6 and R.Category5 > R.Category7 and R.Category5 > R.Category8 then 'Category5'
            when R.Category6 > R.Category1 and R.Category6 > R.Category2 and R.Category6 > R.Category3 and R.Category6 > R.Category4 and R.Category6 > R.Category5 and R.Category6 > R.Category7 and R.Category6 > R.Category8 then 'Category6'
            when R.Category7 > R.Category1 and R.Category7 > R.Category2 and R.Category7 > R.Category3 and R.Category7 > R.Category4 and R.Category7 > R.Category5 and R.Category7 > R.Category6 and R.Category7 > R.Category8 then 'Category7'
            when R.Category8 > R.Category1 and R.Category8 > R.Category2 and R.Category8 > R.Category3 and R.Category8 > R.Category4 and R.Category8 > R.Category5 and R.Category8 > R.Category6 and R.Category8 > R.Category7 then 'Category8'     
            else 'Tie'
         end
     from Revenue as R
     where R.Email = C.Email
)
```

That wouldn't limit the comparisons to only those categories involved in the first tie though without a little more work.

Comment: I've tried that, but, since i'm running on SQL Server 2005, i'm getting this error:

"Only one expression can be specified in the select list when the subquery is not introduced with EXISTS."

Comment: I don't think that error or that logic is specific to 2005, though `case` can have some odd limitations at times especially with subqueries. But I only see one expression in the select list...